# How to handle angular module dependencies in other directories?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Let's say that, I have a main module:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.view1']);
```

And the other module

```
angular.module('myApp.view1', ['ngRoute'])
```

the second one is in another directory in the project.The first module cannot find it's dependency, only if I also add

```
<script src="view1/view1.js"></script> in the index.html
```

,but it quickly becomes pretty hard to manage by hand, if one has lots of javascript files.
What is the best way to manage dependencies between angular modules, so that they can recognize each other?

Comment: You can use task runners like grunt or gulp to add those files automatically in your index.html the moment they are created.
And what @Rias says is something you should only do when you are ready to put it on production.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a task runner like [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) or [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) and concatenate all the javascript files during the build step and include that one file in your index.html file. I use gulp and here is a sample gulp task that helps you concatenate all the JS files using the gulp-concat plugin.

**gulpfile.js**

```
var gulp = require("gulp");
var concat = require("gulp-concat");

//if all your source js files are inside the src directory
var srcJs = ["src/**/*.js"];

gulp.task("js", function() {
    return gulp.src(srcJs)
               .pipe(concat("app.js") // concat into 1 file called app.js
               .pipe(gulp.dest("dist"); //save app.js in dist directory
});
```

So add this gulpfile.js in your project root folder and every time you make code changes, go to the project root folder in the command line and run the command "gulp js". This will run the js task and concatenate all your JS files and store it in a file called app.js in the dist directory. And in your index.html file you can always point to this one file dist/app.js.

Comment: With a slight tweak you can use the gulp watch capabilities with the result that saving any of your javascript files will automatically create a new app.js

Answer (score 2):

They can only recognize each other, if they are added as script files. A best practice is to minify all of the javascript files within your directory structure into one file before publishing.